# Force Java compiler not to inline final static fields

Tags: java, eclipse

I found that sometimes, if not always, static final fields will be inlined at the bytecode level. For some reason, I don't like this to happen. How do I switch this compile option off? Especially within Eclipse 4. (Without touching the source code.)

Thanks

Comment: You want the compiler to stop from replacing statically analyzable unmutable code? What for?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @Smutjie For part of some software engineering study using dynamic analysis. Using a static final field is different from hard-coding a constant in the program at source code level.

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I consider changing the compiler option and changing the source code are different...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a compile-time options.

Puzzle 93: Class Warfare,  in the *Java Puzzlers* book discusses this.  There can be bugs produced since null does not get "inlined".

There's a workaround to refer to them via a do-nothing function, e.g.:

```
public class Words {

    private Words() { }; // Uninstantiable
    public static final String FIRST  = ident("the");
    public static final String SECOND = ident(null);
    public static final String THIRD  = ident("set");

    private static String ident(String s) {
       return s;
    }

}
```

Obviously, this requires modifying your source code extensively.  Not what you wanted...

Either [buy the book](http://www.javapuzzlers.com/), or [see here for a more complete discussion](http://softcycle.blogspot.com/2012/09/puzzle-93-class-warfare.html)

Comment: Thanks. But I am just considering the compiler options if possible.